# How do I use angular language service?

Tags: angular, typescript, atom-editor

I want to use the angular language service feature of being able to do completion on template files.

I'm trying to get the plugin to work with an Atom package i use [atom-typescript](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript).

I've added fixed up the package to be be activated on html files as well.

this is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "plugins": [{ "name": "@angular/language-service" }],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

this is the package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.4",
```

The atom-typescript uses typescripts tsserver. So I'm pretty sure that works. put some log traces and I can see the angular language service does get initialize.

What am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not supported in atom-typescript yet.

More infos:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1278
and
https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1355